# Prove a space is totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the set of $\{0, 1\}$ sequences,

$X = \{(a_1, a_2, . . .) : a_i ∈ \{0, 1\}\}$

with the following metric
$d((a_n),(b_n)) := 1/k$, where $a_k \neq b_k $ and $a_n = b_n$ for all $n < k$.

Prove the space $X$ is totally bounded; that is, for every $ε > 0$ there exists a finite set

$F_\epsilon = \{x^1 , . . . , x^N \} ⊂ X$ such that $ min_i\ d(x^i, x) < ε $ for any $x ∈ X$

Comment: you may try to even prove that the space in question is compact. Topologically it is the product $\{0,1\}^\omega$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology (and $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers, including $0$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$,  consider an integer $n$ such that ${1\over n}<\epsilon$.

Let $P(n)$ the set whose elements are maps $\{0,..,,n\}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ for every $y\in P(n)$, consider $x_y$ such that $(x_y)_i=f(i), i\leq n, (x_y)_i=0, i>n$. For every $x\in X$, there exists $x_y$ such that the first $n$-coordinates of $x_y$ and $x$ are equal, it implies that $d(x,x_y)<{1\over n}<\epsilon$.